# 20.04 virtualbox-guest-dkms: Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)

Tags: apt, 20.04, kernel, virtualbox

How to fix this?
/var/crash/virtualbox-guest-dkms.0.crash contains:

```
ProblemType: Package
DKMSBuildLog:
 DKMS make.log for virtualbox-guest-6.1.10 for kernel 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
 Sun 10 Jan 11:53:48 EET 2021
 make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic'
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest-linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/common/string/strformatrt.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/combined-agnostic.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/combined-os-specific.o
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/combined-os-specific.c:30:
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemAllocExecVmArea’:
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:171:15: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__get_vm_area’; did you mean ‘get_vm_area’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   171 |     pVmArea = __get_vm_area(cbAlloc, VM_ALLOC, MODULES_VADDR, MODULES_END);
       |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
       |               get_vm_area
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:171:13: warning: assignment to ‘struct vm_struct *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   171 |     pVmArea = __get_vm_area(cbAlloc, VM_ALLOC, MODULES_VADDR, MODULES_END);
       |             ^
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:204:14: error: implicit declaration of function ‘map_vm_area’; did you mean ‘get_vm_area’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   204 |         if (!map_vm_area(pVmArea, PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC,
       |              ^~~~~~~~~~~
       |              get_vm_area
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/combined-os-specific.c:33:
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemObjNativeFree’:
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:596:43: error: ‘struct mm_struct’ has no member named ‘mmap_sem’; did you mean ‘mmap_base’?
   596 |                     down_read(&pTask->mm->mmap_sem);
       |                                           ^~~~~~~~
       |                                           mmap_base
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:611:41: error: ‘struct mm_struct’ has no member named ‘mmap_sem’; did you mean ‘mmap_base’?
   611 |                     up_read(&pTask->mm->mmap_sem);
       |                                         ^~~~~~~~
       |                                         mmap_base
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemObjNativeLockUser’:
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1079:31: error: ‘struct mm_struct’ has no member named ‘mmap_sem’; did you mean ‘mmap_base’?
  1079 |         down_read(&pTask->mm->mmap_sem);
       |                               ^~~~~~~~
       |                               mmap_base
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1165:33: error: ‘struct mm_struct’ has no member named ‘mmap_sem’; did you mean ‘mmap_base’?
  1165 |             up_read(&pTask->mm->mmap_sem);
       |                                 ^~~~~~~~
       |                                 mmap_base
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1192:29: error: ‘struct mm_struct’ has no member named ‘mmap_sem’; did you mean ‘mmap_base’?
  1192 |         up_read(&pTask->mm->mmap_sem);
       |                             ^~~~~~~~
       |                             mmap_base
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemObjNativeMapUser’:
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1607:36: error: ‘struct mm_struct’ has no member named ‘mmap_sem’; did you mean ‘mmap_base’?
  1607 |             down_write(&pTask->mm->mmap_sem);
       |                                    ^~~~~~~~
       |                                    mmap_base
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1724:34: error: ‘struct mm_struct’ has no member named ‘mmap_sem’; did you mean ‘mmap_base’?
  1724 |             up_write(&pTask->mm->mmap_sem);
       |                                  ^~~~~~~~
       |                                  mmap_base
 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
 make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:290: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/combined-os-specific.o] Error 1
 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:519: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest] Error 2
 make: *** [Makefile:1780: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build] Error 2
 make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic'
DKMSKernelVersion: 5.8.0-36-generic
Date: Sun Jan 10 11:53:52 2021
DuplicateSignature: dkms:virtualbox-guest-dkms:6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1:/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:171:15: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__get_vm_area’; did you mean ‘get_vm_area’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
Package: virtualbox-guest-dkms 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1
PackageVersion: 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1
SourcePackage: virtualbox
Title: virtualbox-guest-dkms 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1: virtualbox-guest kernel module failed to build
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Downloading and installing VirtualBox 6.1.16 with dpkg ([solution](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-virtualbox-not-working-when-installing/) linked in [a comment by Janaka Priyadarshana](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306674/20-04-virtualbox-guest-dkms-error-bad-return-status-for-module-build-on-kernel/1306813#comment2223388_1306897)) works.

> 1. Visit https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
> 2. Download the one that is applicable to your system.
> 3. Run from bash: `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb` to install it.

Comment: I spent a whole day trying to solve this issue. Your answer saved me.

Comment: I had to first remove virtualbox-dkms and virtualbox (with "sudo apt remove x") then the dpkg -i reported missing dependencies so had to do a "sudo apt -get -f install". Now it's finally workin

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same situation. I went back to kernel 5.4: this has solved the problem.

Comment: How did you do this ?

Comment: At boot time, you should access the GRUB menu and select there which kernel you want to use. In general you access the GRUB menu pressing the `ESC` key a couple of times as soon as you've powered on your device ...

Comment: I got to solve by following the instructions given in
https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-virtualbox-not-working-when-installing/